# Label depends on field value

Tags: symfony-1.4

Hi is there chance that I can change field label depends on fields value
ex.

- when is_active = 1 set label = Active
- when is_active = 0 set label = In active

in yaml

Comment: Are you tolking about generator.yml?! However it is possible to add conditions to yml, but you should modify a lot of code in various files. Why not consider a few line of jQuery code?

Comment: I thought that there is simple way to achive that